# Desplegar Aplicación JSF en Tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, maven

llevo ya varias horas con el mismo problema. He comenzado hace poco con JSF y he creado una aplicación Web JSF con Maven muy sencila y al ejecutarla desde eclise haciendo run as/run on server la aplicación se muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que si ejecuto un Maven build... poniendo en goals: tomcat7:deploy o mismamente haciendo click derecho en el proyecto y exportándolo como un war, me ocurre lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La aplicación se despliega, y puedo acceder a ella:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero como podeis ver no se muestra ningún elemento JSF (ni inputs ni el botón). Si inspecciono la página si aparecen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna ayuda por favor, ¡estoy desesperado!
Gracias!!

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de muchas horas he encontrado la solución:
En el web.xml he sustituido:

```
 < servlet-mapping>
    < servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    < url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
< /servlet-mapping>
```

por:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando un poco, al levantar el archivo directamente desde run as server es capaz de cargarlo con tomcat, pero cuando no se levanta el xhtml directamente y lo desplegamos en tomcat entonces necesitamos agregar la ruta correcta.